# Remove specific points from linestring postgis

Tags: postgis, linestring

I am working with a data set that has been using the (0 0) point to pad any points that were missing when the linestring was created. So now the query

```
SELECT 
    id, route as line 
FROM 
    trips
WHERE 
    ST_Contains(route, ST_PointFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326))
```

Returns some linestrings where a point or two has been set 0 0 and some where the entire linestring is 0 0's.

Is there a way get the index of ST_PointFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326) from a linestring so I can delete it?

EDIT

Removing the lines that are all 0 0 points is trivial now that I think about it.

```
DELETE

FROM 
    trips
WHERE 
    ST_Contains(route, ST_PointFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326))
AND 
    ST_LENGTH(route) = 0
```

I am still trying to remove the points in lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) to get individual points and then [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to rebuild the LineString, with a NOT ST_EQUALS in the WHERE clause to eliminate the Point(0,0);

```
WITH 
   lines (ls) AS 
      (VALUES  (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1 -1, 0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'))), 
   dumped (pts) AS 
      (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ls)).* FROM lines)
   SELECT ST_MakeLine(dumped.geom) 
   FROM dumped 
   WHERE NOT ST_EQUALS(geom, ST_MakePoint(0,0));
```

If you wrap the ST_MakeLine in ST_AsText, you will see that this returns:

> LINESTRING(-1 -1,1 1,2 2)

Though you didn't ask this, there are probably better ways of dealing with incomplete LineStrings than adding a Point(0, 0), but I'm sure you know this anyway.

Comment: Another way could be to use ST_DumpPoints for finding the indices of (0 0) points and remove those from the linestrings with ST_RemovePoint http://postgis.net/docs/ST_RemovePoint.html.

Comment: @user30184. True, and that did occur to me, though I think it is slighly more complex to write. I wonder if there is any significant performance difference between rebuilding a LineString and removing from an existing one?

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks for the answer! What would be some other options in terms of dealing with missing points in the line string? Right now I am considering omitting them entirely.

Comment: I don't know without knowing where the linestrings come from and what they are representing -- GPS feed along a route, for example? Using Point(0,0) for missing data struck me as similar as using 0 rather than null for a numeric field. But without knowing more, that might be an unfair judgement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to remove points from lines using `ST_RemovePoint`.

Assuming table=`my_lines` and geometry field=`geom`.

```
UPDATE my_lines
SET geom = ST_RemovePoint(geom, t.pt_num-1)
FROM 
(SELECT line_id, pt_num FROM
  (SELECT id line_id, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path[1] pt_num, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom geom
    FROM my_lines) my_points
  WHERE ST_Equals(geom, ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'))) t
WHERE id = t.line_id
```